# Определить, на что идёт запрос: IP или сайт

Tags: ip, linux

Добрый вечер!

На сервере добавлен сайт, он установлен по умолчанию для IP адреса. При запросе IP адреса можно получить доступ к контенту сайта.

Как определить, идёт запрос на сайт или на IP адрес?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверять хост, который указан в заголовке запроса, и сравнивать его с хостом сайта. Там окажется либо хост сайта, либо айпи (в теории там может оказаться вообще что угодно, но так вряд ли кто-то развлекается). В PHP это `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.